# change tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d to 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

How can I change `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d` to 2.0.0 so that I can use it in the context of tensorflow-2.0.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Glorot normal initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/GlorotNormal)**, also called **Xavier normal initializer** in `TF 2.x` in place of `xavier_initializer_conv2d()`.

```
tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(
    seed=None
)
```

Also, `tf.contrib.layers` is deprecated in `TF 2.x` and replaced with [TF slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim).

This [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) might be helpful for you to convert `TF 1.x` code to `TF 2.x`.